# VBA match on IP and write to cell not working

Tags: excel, regex, vba

writing macro to extract IP out of many cells and buried in text. I need to find the IP and then copy each to a new blank cell.
I get the results "not matched". Please advise as I'm over thinking this.

To test I filled 40 cells with "this is a ip test 8.8.8.8 oh no"

```
Private Sub simpleRegex()
    Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b" 'find IP
    Dim Match As Object
    Dim matches As Object

    Dim regex As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim Myrange As Range

    Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A39") 'within this range
    
    Dim i As Long, strMatches As String
    i = 1 'row number where we start to write

    For Each cell In Myrange
        If strPattern <> "" Then
            strInput = cell.Value

            With regex
                .Global = True
                .MultiLine = True
                .IgnoreCase = False
                .Pattern = strPattern
            End With

            If regex.Test(strInput) Then 'if ip found do this
                Set matches = regex.Execute(strInput)
                strMatches = vbNullString
                For Each Match In matches
                'strMatches = strMatches 'collect all matches ip?
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("U" & i).Value = strMatches 'write the matches into cell
                i = i + 1
                Next
            Else
                MsgBox ("Not matched")
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What was the result of your test?

Comment: As mentioned above get the results "not matched".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me (re-arranged the output a bit)

```vb
Private Sub simpleRegex()
    
    Dim strPattern As String:
    Dim Match As Object
    Dim matches As Object
    Dim strMatches As String
    Dim regex As Object
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim Myrange As Range, cell As Range, cOut as Range
    
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    strPattern = "\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b" 'find IP
    With regex
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With
    
    Set cOut = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") 'start output here
    Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A39") 'within this range

    For Each cell In Myrange
        strInput = cell.Value
        If Len(strInput) > 0 Then
            If regex.Test(strInput) Then 'if ip found do this
                Set matches = regex.Execute(strInput)
                strMatches = vbNullString
                For Each Match In matches
                    cOut.Value = Match.Value 'write the match into cell
                    Set cOut = cOut.Offset(1, 0)'next cell down
                Next
            Else
                'cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "No matches"
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Indeed this does work! TY! how can I make the output go to sheet2?

Comment: TY so much. Was pounding my head trying to figure out what I was missing. Also thanks for the comments in the code. This will def help me later!